# How to prevent file from renaming from users using C++ code

Tags: linux, windows

I want to prevent a file from the user, so he can't rename it though it should be visible. I want to achieve this programmatically using C++.

Answer (score 0):

When renaming a file, write permissions to the file don't matter since the change is to the directory, not the file. That's changing the directory entry to have a different name pointing to the file.

You can use some `std::filesystem` functions  to solve this by modifying the permissions of that file .

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main(){
fs::permissions("{__path_to_the_file__",
                    fs::perms::owner_all|fs::perms::others_read);
 }
```

---

> This function was introduced in the STL as part of C++ 17 , if you want to use a previous version you may use `boost::filesystem` and its functions which are similar to the STL ones mentioned above.